# jquery click event fires before click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I was creating a small todo app and encountered an issue which looks like the alert message runs before the click event fires. it doesn't look like the event is registered at all. Can anybody tell me why this happen?

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var MyTodo = {
        init: function() {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvent();
            this.addTask();

        },
        cacheDom: function() {
            this.$title = $('#inpTitle');
            this.$date = $('#inpDate');
            this.$description = $('#inpDescription');
            this.$addTaskBtn = $('#addTaskBtn');
            this.$pending = $('#pending');
        },
        addTask: function() {
            if (!this.$title.val()) {
                alert('please enter title');
                return;
            }
            var value = '<ul class="todo-task" id="todoList" draggable="true"><li><strong>' + this.$title.val() + '</strong></li>' +
                '<li>' + this.$date.val() + '</li>' +
                '<li>' + this.$description.val() + '</li></ul>';

            this.$pending.append(value);

            // empty inputs
            this.$title.val('');
            this.$date.val('');
            this.$description.val('');
        },
        bindEvent: function() {
            this.$addTaskBtn.on('click', this.addTask.bind(this));

        }

    };

    MyTodo.init();
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are invoking `this.addTask();` in `init`, `init` method will get invoked and hence it will `alert()`. Remove `this.addTask` invocation  from `init()`

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var MyTodo = {
    init: function() {
      this.cacheDom();
      this.bindEvent();

    },
    cacheDom: function() {
      this.$title = $('#inpTitle');
      this.$date = $('#inpDate');
      this.$description = $('#inpDescription');
      this.$addTaskBtn = $('#addTaskBtn');
      this.$pending = $('#pending');
    },
    addTask: function() {
      if (!this.$title.val()) {
        alert('please enter title');
        return;
      }
      var value = '<ul class="todo-task" id="todoList" draggable="true"><li><strong>' + this.$title.val() + '</strong></li>' +
        '<li>' + this.$date.val() + '</li>' +
        '<li>' + this.$description.val() + '</li></ul>';

      this.$pending.append(value);

      // empty inputs
      this.$title.val('');
      this.$date.val('');
      this.$description.val('');
    },
    bindEvent: function() {
      this.$addTaskBtn.on('click', this.addTask.bind(this));

    }

  };

  MyTodo.init();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todoWrapper" class="container">
  <div class="todo" id="pending" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <h3 class="text-center">Pending</h3>


  </div>
  <div class="todo" id="inProgress" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <h3 class="text-center">In Progress</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="todo" id="completed" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <h3 class="text-center">Completed</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="addTask" class="todo">
    <h2 class="text-center">Add Task</h2>

    <div>
      <input type="text" name="" id="inpTitle" placeholder="title">
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea name="" id="inpDescription" cols="23" rows="3" placeholder="description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="date" name="" id="inpDate" placeholder="due date">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="addTaskBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Add Task</button>
      <button id="clearTaskBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Clear Task</button>
    </div>



    <div class="delete" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <audio id="sfx" src="media/dump.wav"></audio>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that and didn't help. It runs once on the page load.

Comment: `this.$addTaskBtn = $('#addTaskBtn');` is set as `cacheDom` is called first. OP is calling `addTask` for some reason which is why the alert is being fired. It would seem it is supposed to only be called upon click event

Comment: @PatrickEvans I just made the changes and still fires on page load